# Ошибка установки Vue Cli через NPM (Тут решение, так как ответа нет нигде. Пользуйтесь)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-cli

```
C:\Users\hp>npm install -g @vue/cli 
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @apollo/federation@0.12.0: Regression with the @deprecated directive, fixed in v0.12.1
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3
```

А за тем вылетает сбой, вывод консоли не успел сохранить, так как починил неожиданно всё, но там в общем зависало на этапе "build [что-то там] bin/vue.js" и следом вылезало NPM WARN и что-то типа [имя модуля] {"os", "name"}. Точно не помню.

В общем, все в интернете советуют удалить NPM и потом заново поставить. НЕ сработало. При всём при этом я обновил core-js до 3 версии, тоже самое с @apollo/federation. NPM в PATH добавил. Vue полностью удалял командой npm uninstall vue. Не помогало.

Что я сделал: идём по пути "C:\User\CurrentUser\AppData\Roaming\npm" и там удаляем все файлы и папки с именем vue. Дальше запускаем npm uninstall vue. И потом выполняем npm install -g @vue/cli. То есть ставим Vue Cli без установленного Vue. И всё. Он ругается потом при установке WARN'ами, но в итоге ставит заветную vue/cli 4.2.2. И теперь можно пользоваться vue ui и вообще полностью фреймворком.

P.s. После всего этого npm install -g vue делать не надо, был бы я новичком, я бы именно так и сделал, так что оставляю это тут

Comment: Запостите ответ в ответ, а не в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что я сделал: идём по пути "C:\User\CurrentUser\AppData\Roaming\npm" и там удаляем все файлы и папки с именем vue. Дальше запускаем npm uninstall vue. И потом выполняем npm install -g @vue/cli. То есть ставим Vue Cli без установленного Vue. И всё. Он ругается потом при установке WARN'ами, но в итоге ставит заветную vue/cli 4.2.2. И теперь можно пользоваться vue ui и вообще полностью фреймворком.

P.s. После всего этого npm install -g vue делать не надо, был бы я новичком, я бы именно так и сделал, так что оставляю это тут